# How can get array key value from object using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this cart object array

```
 Array
(
    [16] => Array
        (
            [count] => 1
            [data] => CartItem Object
                (
                    [_itemID] => 16
                    [_itemData] => 
                )
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [count] => 1
            [data] => CartItem Object
                (
                    [_itemID] => 14
                    [_itemData] => 
                )
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [count] => 1
            [data] => CartItem Object
                (
                    [_itemID] => 18
                    [_itemData] => 
                )
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [count] => 1
            [data] => CartItem Object
                (
                    [_itemID] => 15
                    [_itemData] => 
                )
        )
)
```

From this array I want to get these key values 16, 14, 18, 15.

How can I get this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array_keys` will give the keys of a particular array:

```
$keys = array_keys($yourArray);
print_r($keys);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `array_keys` function.

http://php.net/array_keys

Answer (score 2):

Also you could do that in a foreach loop

```
foreach($array as $key=>$nextArray){
    //Process
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To return all the keys of the array use (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php):

```
array_keys($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the php [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) documentation that should do what you want.

```
$numbers = new array();
foreach ($cart as $key => $value) {
    array_push($numbers, $key);
}
```